# How to enable Intel HAXM for Android emulator inside Android Studio on Ubuntu

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, haxm

The link at [intel.com](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2012/03/12/how-to-start-intel-hardware-assisted-virtualization-hypervisor-on-linux-to-speed-up-intel-android-x86-emulator) has the instructions for Eclipse IDE.

In the Additional Emulator Command Line Options field, enter:
-qemu -m 2047 -enable-kvm

However, Not sure where to specify these options when running emulator from Android Studio.

Comment: If you create an AVD using an x86 system image, it should just work without having to specify extra command line options.

Comment: Though note that you do need to have KVM installed, which is available through standard Ubuntu channels (e.g., **`apt-get`**).